# Angular + .NET Core Web API + Cookie Authentication + Same Domain = Secure?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

I have yet to find an example of Angular authentication using a .NET Core Web API backend and cookie authentication. I discovered back in 2019 that as long as the angular SPA is being served from the same domain as the API, it is "OK" to use cookie authentication.

**Reference:**
https://damienbod.com/2019/01/20/is-a-spa-less-secure-than-a-server-rendered-web-application/

**Angular**

```
const credentials = {
    UserName: userName,
    Password: password
};
this.httpClient.post<AuthorizationInfo>(url, credentials, { withCredentials: true });
```

**.NET Core 5.0 Web API** (code stripped for brevity)

```
(startup.cs)
            // Configure cookie authentication.
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options => {
                options.Cookie.Name = AUTH_COOKIE_NAME;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });

(AuthenticationController.cs)
[HttpPost]
public async Task<AuthorizationInfo> Login([FromBody] UserInfo credentials)
{
    if (this.authenticationStore.Authenticate(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password))
    {
        // ... (claims)

        // Create the user's identity and create an authorization cookie.
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await this.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), new AuthenticationProperties() {
            IsPersistent = true
        });

        return new AuthorizationInfo() {
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Roles = roleNames
        };
    }
    else 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

With the above implementation, once the authentication is successful, the client will send the cookie upon all other requests, and the entire thing works perfectly and is amazingly simple.

**The million dollar question is:**
Is there something fundamentally wrong with the above approach, such that is bad practice to mix SPA and cookie authentication on the same domain? Can you provide any online evidence to back up your assertions?

I already aware of the argument that serving your application and identity logic from the same application is not good practice. Besides that, I've searched high and low for any evidence that suggests the above implementation is "bad practice" but I have not found any. Absence of evidence does not imply it is a good pattern, or, not a "bad pattern." Every Angular or SPA example I see uses separate identity servers or services, tokens, oidc, etc.

**Bonus:** Are there any non-fundamental, but inherent aspects/risk one should be aware of with this approach that should be mitigated, such as CSRF, etc.? (Any links are appreciated, but not required, as the question is very broad).

Comment: I think asking if cookie authentication is "bad" is not as good a question as asking: when using all of the technology components (angular, asp.net core) what authentication approaches are popular? There may be good reasons for using a not so common approach, but I think its better to first find the most common. Why not try oauth? what is binding you to using cookie based? If you could outline your argument in favor of using cookie based over oauth, that may help readers to understand.

Comment: SPAs and OAuth suffer from some problems, which have some workarounds. It's unfortunately not easy but I find this article to be really good and touch many points, including cookie authentication: https://brockallen.com/2019/01/03/the-state-of-the-implicit-flow-in-oauth2/

Comment: @jbooker As a software architect, ironically inexperienced with web development, after doing research on authentication, SPA's, etc. back in 2019, it was clear that OAuth was the way to go. That is/was the "industry guidance." However, we struggled getting that implemented technically, and a very experienced co-worker pushed for the "same domain/app cookie authentication" and was able to implement it quite easily. I am not for or against it, as I have no way with my lack of experience to know if it is indeed wrong. The simplicity is welcome, but the *full* scope of the risks unknown to me.

Comment: @jpgrassi Yes that article you posted was mind blowing when I read it back then. Had it not been for that article, I would have stopped us from moving forward with cookie authentication. According to [draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-07](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-07) it reads: "OAuth adds additional attack vectors that could be avoided with a different solution." and "Instead, a more secure design is to use an HTTP-only cookie between the JavaScript application and API so that the JavaScript code can't access the cookie value itself."

Comment: @jbooker See my link and comment above which seems to give the strongest argument for the cookie authentication in our simple application architecture. Whether or not we did it "correctly" I don't 100% know since I can't find any same domain cookie auth examples.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with cookie authentication, given the requirements of your project. If the SPA is always served together with the back-end, in the same domain, why complicate things? Your back-end can also authenticate requests with oauth, if you decide to open it for other types of integrations, such as partners and other apps, although at that point I would probably create another API. You can also search for BFF - back-end for front-end.